# how to load moment.js into webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, momentjs

I want to load moment.js as a plugin into webpack. Does anyone know how to do so? I get the error "moment" is not defined when trying to call `define('moment')` in my backbone view

here's my webpack configuration:

```
app.use(webpackMiddleware(webpack({
    context: __dirname + '/src',
    entr: './admin-entry.js',
    entry: {
        'admin-entry': './admin-entry.js',
        'admin-login': './admin-login.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: '/webpack',
        publicPath: '/webpack',
        filename: '[name].js'
    },

    module: {
        noParse: [
            new RegExp(jqueryPath),
            new RegExp(lodashPath),
            new RegExp(qPath),
            new RegExp(cookiePath),
            new RegExp(momentPath),
            new RegExp(dateRangePickerPath)
        ]

    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'jquery': jqueryPath,
            'lodash': lodashPath,
            'underscore': lodashPath,
            'backbone': backbonePath,
            'cookie': cookiePath,
            'daterangepicker': dateRangePickerPath,
            'moment': momentPath,
            'q': qPath
        },
        modulesDirectories: [
            'node_modules'
        ]
    },
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    plugins: [
        new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin('webpack/[file].map', null, '[absolute-resource-path]', '[absolute-resource-path]')
    ]
}), {
    noInfo: false,
    quiet: false,
    lazy: false,
    // switch into lazy mode
    // that means no watching, but recompilation on every request
    watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 300,
        poll: true
    },
    publicPath: '/webpack',
    // public path to bind the middleware to
    // use the same as in webpack

    stats: {
        colors: true
    }
}));
```

Comment: Did you install moment via npm ? For me it's fine with `alias: { "moment": 'moment/min/moment-with-locales'`

Answer (score 2):

At first, ensure that you install moment with npm command

> npm install moment

Now you should have moment in your node_modules folder. Then you should add moment to your project as a global variable so you should change Webpack to resolve it for you.To do this change your webpack.config.js file as below:

```
    plugins: [
      .... 
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          moment : 'moment'
      })
      ....
    ]
```